# Is both spring force and friction force are equal in this problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, spring

[image]

I draw a F.B.D of point "A" of a spring(whose spring constant=k and it is massless, elongation form natural length=l). If a person pulls a spring in right direction by making contact at point "A" then the force acting at point "A" are Normal force from upper finger (N2) in downward direction, from lower finger(N1) in upper direction and static friction from upper hand right direction(fs1) similarly from lower hand in right direction as (fs2). so form this can we say that the spring force(Fsp) applied on hand will be equal and opposite to static friction (fs1+fs2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If the end of the spring is not moving then the spring force is equal and opposite to the sum of the frictional forces.

Answer (score 0):

If the spring is at rest, you can say $f_{sp1} + f_{sp1} = kx$.

One more thing is $N_1 = N_2$ and hence, $f_{sp1} = f_{sp1}$.